# Are there any other spells in bant colors that will cause Enduring Scalelord to go infinite?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building, mtg-commander

Are there creatures, artifacts, enchantments, etc that will make [Enduring Scalelord](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Enduring%20Scalelord) go infinite in [Bant](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Bant)?

I'm building a Bant counters EDH deck and it'd be fun to have ES blow up in a couple of different ways. I have [Progenitor Mimic](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Progenitor%20Mimic) in the deck and I know ES would also benefit from the [Archangel of Thune](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Archangel%20of%20Thune)/[Spike Feeder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spike%20Feeder) combo.  I'm blanking on anything else that wouldn't just stop at 1 trigger.

Comment: Every clone ever and putting a +1/+1 counter on a creature through any means?

Comment: Are you looking for single-card combos or will multi-card ones work too? Since looking the only single-card combos I am finding are Clone variants.

Comment: Hi Diego - I'm honestly open to anything?  I'm still a relatively new player, so I don't really know a lot of the cards in the older formats.  What I had in mind was anything that might say something like 'when a counter is placed on a creature, place a counter on another creature' or something to that effect?  That way the triggers could bounce off each other.  But lacking that, multi card combos would work too!

Answer (score 7):

Yes. [Cackling Counterpart](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cackling%20Counterpart) and [Battlegrowth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Battlegrowth) are in Bant colors and combo with Enduring Scalelord.

**Can you teach me how to search for cards myself?**

Introducing the [Gatherer's advanced search feature](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Advanced.aspx). We know that Enduring Scalelord goes infinite with itself. Let's try to find a clone in Bant colors. Here is what I started with:

- Color:
- Does NOT contain Black
- Does NOT contain Red
- Rules Text:
- Does contain "copy"
- Does contain "target creature"

Tons of results. Let's try narrowing it down. Instants are nice if they are cheap, so let's see if we can find one.

- Card Type:
- Does contain Instant"

Still a lot of false positives. I notice a lot of "copy target spell" cards. We don't want those.

- Rules Text:
- Does not contain "spell"

[Here is the final result](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+%5B%22copy%22%5D+%5B%22target%20creature%22%5D+!%5Bspell%5D&type=+%5B%22Instant%22%5D&color=+!%5BR%5D+!%5BB%5D). The top four cards are all three mana instant speed spells that can copy your Enduring Scalelord. Nice.

I repeated this process to find Battlegrowth, but I'll leave the exact search as an exercise for you. Learning how to mine the Gatherer is far more valuable being handed a list of cards.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get an infinite combo with Enduring Scalelord is to use another Enduring Scalelord (probably with a copy in EDH). Once you have that, any effect that puts a +1/+1 counter on any creature you control will set off the combo.

When I'm looking for cards, I like to use [magiccards.info](http://magiccards.info/), which has some very nice advanced search features. Commander uses color identity to restrict card legality, so all of our searches need to start with

> ci:wug

This finds only cards that have white, blue, and/or green in their color identity (including colorless cards). Once we have that, we can use similar search terms to the ones Rainbolt used:

> o:copy o:creature -o:spell -o:populate

This will find cards with "copy" and "creature" in their text, but without "spell" (because most if not all spell copying effects don't let you copy creature spells). I also ignored cards with "populate" in their text, because that only copies tokens, so it will only be marginally useful in this situation. The [resulting search](http://magiccards.info/query?q=ci%3Awug%20o%3Acopy%20o%3Acreature%20-o%3Aspell%20-o%3Apopulate&v=card&s=cname) returns 41 different cards, most of which will be useful here, including

- [Clone](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Clone), and similar creatures that enter as copies of other creatures
- Spells like [Cytoshape](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cytoshape), which turn creatures into copies of other creatures (temporarily).
- Cards like [Fated Infatuation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fated%20Infatuation), which create token copies of creatures

It does also find a few irrelevant cards though, like [Back from the Brink](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Back%20from%20the%20Brink), which can't copy creatures on the battlefield, and [Essence of the Wild](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Essence%20of%20the%20Wild), which can only copy itself.

Now, all we need is a way to put a +1/+1 counter on any creature you control. The simplest search here is to just look for every card with "+1/+1 counter" in its text. The [resulting search](http://magiccards.info/query?q=ci%3Awug%20o%3A%22%2B1%2F%2B1%20counter%22&v=card&s=cname) finds 489 cards, and it turns out that just about every one of them can trigger Enduring Scalelord. Some highlights that would be very useful even without the copy are

- [Ajani Steadfast](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ajani%20Steadfast), [Cathar's Crusade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=389459), [Cradle of Vitality](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cradle%20of%20Vitality), [Decree of Savagery](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Decree%20of%20Savagery), [Gavony Township](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gavony%20Township), and [Mikaeus, the Lunarch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mikaeus%2C%20the%20Lunarch), all of which can put counters on all of your creatures (giving you as many Enduring Scalelord triggers as you have creatures)
- [Aquastrand Spider](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Aquastrand%20Spider), [Bramblewood Paragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bramblewood%20Paragon), [Cenn's Tactician](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=152878), and [Crowned Ceratok](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crowned%20Ceratok): creatures that grant abilities to creatures with +1/+1 counters
- [Avenger of Zendikar](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Avenger%20of%20Zendikar), which can put a counters on large number of tokens every turn.
- [Custodi Soulbinders](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Custodi%20Soulbinders), [Etched Oracle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Etched%20Oracle), [Lunar Avenger](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lunar%20Avenger), [Sage of Hours](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sage%20of%20Hours), and [Simic Manipulator](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Simic%20Manipulator): Creatures that can do something useful with the counters once they get them.

There are more cards in each of those lists, and many of the other cards can be more or less useful depending on what else you have in your deck.